# Streaming data from client with HTTP Post

Tags: http, post, stream, restlet

I would like to stream data from the client to the server.

My application streams audio data to the server.  I do not know how long the audio will be when I begin streaming it.  I want to reduce latency by transmitting the data as it is being recorded.  Once all the data has been uploaded, then I will process it.

So, what I would like is a HTTP POST where the body is streamed.  At the client, the POST would be sent as the data is available.  At the server end, I would like it to arrive like a normal POST with a complete body of collected data.

I am currently using Restlet, and implementing my stream as a Chunked POST to the Restlet framework.

However, I can not find a client API that allows me to begin the POST, then start streaming the data.

I haven't found anything useful searching the archive.  Can anyone give me a pointer here.  Can HTTP POST be used this way?  Can I use Restlet for this?  Is there another standard pattern/API for streaming from the client to the server?

Many thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: Depending on the application / client the [Websocket protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Nice, Thanks Stephan.  Does Websocket work on Android and iOS?

Comment: Yes it does! jWebSockets looks very nice.  Has anyone tried it?  Other recommendations?

Comment: On Android I have used [Weberknecht](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/) which however has not seen a release for some time now, so I am not sure whether it is still under development. For C++ I know about [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/software/websocket%2B%2B), however I never used it.

Answer (score 7):

Going to answer my own question for those that come after.

Here is a nice tutorial on streaming requests with Apache HttpClient

Search for "Request Streaming:"

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming

Answer (score -6):

> I can not find a client API that allows me to begin the POST

You could always [use a browser](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). Serverside it's just the same a a file upload.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this in my application.  I want to make a laptop Java client for debugging, and then implement Android and iOS.