# How can I get a writeable file object for an HTTP POST in Python?

Tags: python, http, post

I have a Python script which produces some some data. I would like to stream it to an HTTP server using POST. That is, I don't want to accumulate the data in a buffer and then send it -- I just want to send it as it's created. There will be a lot.

The apparently obvious way to do this would be to open the HTTP connection in some way that return a writeable file object, write the data to that object, and then close the connection.

However, it's not obvious to me that this is supported in any of the libraries I looked at (`urllib2`, `httplib`, and `requests`).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This writeable object will have to buffer the data anyway - there isn't a [streamable HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868742/streaming-data-from-client-with-http-post).  You'll have to look at something besides HTTP POST in that case.

Why not buffer the data using StringIO or something and then POST the data.
The following code can be cleaned up, but here's a skeleton using `requests`:

```
import requests
import StringIO

class HttpPostWritable(object):
    def __init__(self, url, init_buffer=''):
        self._url = url
        self._buffer = StringIO.StringIO(init_buffer)

    def write(self, data):
        self._buffer.write(data)

    def close(self):
        requests.post(self._url, self._buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: There's nothing inherent in HTTP or POST that prevents what I'm after. The steps involved in POST are: (1) open a socket to the server, (2) send headers, (3) send post data, (4) read response etc. and other cleanup. I want access to the socket so I can do step 3 myself.

Answer (score -1):

You wont get a writeable file object via urllib2 / urllib. The return value is a "file like" object which supports iteration and reading. If you can read the contents and create your own file object for writing.