# Streaming audio from client to server

Tags: audio, streaming, flash-media-server

For a while, I have been looking for a way to stream/ transfer/ upload (*Not too sure about what is considered as correct, but the source is a client and the destination is a server*). I am a bit familiar with protocols used for streaming as we know it (From Server to Client) but not the other way. I could code it but I was wondering whether there is a better wa, such as using server-side software. 
I would appreciate thoughts, guides and keen on working on that until a solution is found and happy to share any code.
Many thanks

Comment: I have found another post about a similar topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868742/streaming-data-from-client-with-http-post). The guy is suggesting "Request Streaming"... Will have to investigate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stream binary data from client to server using websockets, and this nifty js library.

http://binaryjs.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aby ! I marked it as Answer brcause it sounds about what I needed to do ! though I haven't it yet !