# REST : InputStream and Memory Management

Tags: rest, memory-management, inputstream, bandwidth

Currently, I have a POST end point and the end point accepts an octet-stream. So, I'm wondering where the input-stream gets stored when multiple request keep hitting the server (multiple input-streams cached at network level ?). Do these streams of data packets reside on network and if yes, what  happens if my bandwidth reaches 100%. Also, I am only going to process a request upon validation. So, in such a case I don't process an input-stream if authentication fails. Is this a good approach, considering my applications minimal heap configuration (lets say 2GB). Also, wondering whats the trade-off going to be between memory and bandwidth. I'm using JERSEY implementation (JAVA app) and have deployed the REST service on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

When a RESTful API that uses HTTP as a transport protocol, then the data streams don't get cached in the network layer, as the [HTTP protocol is stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-is-it-said-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol).

With regards to the authentication, before posting the huge load of data, you can do [Basic HTTP Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999295/rest-api-authentication/23691608#23691608), by which your client will retrieve a temporary session token and then post the data.

If you are really concerned that you can reach the network bandwidth, then there are several options you can try to apply:

- Implement asyncronous communication between the client and the server. This way the server will retrieve the input as messages when it's ready to serve them.
- Turn on HTTP compression
- Stream the POST content

More info:

- [REST API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999295/rest-api-authentication)
- [Reducing Your Website's Bandwidth Usage](https://blog.codinghorror.com/reducing-your-websites-bandwidth-usage/)
- [Is it possible to cache POST methods in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)
- [Are REST and HTTP the same thing?](http://restcookbook.com/Miscellaneous/rest-and-http/)
- [Streaming data from client with HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868742/streaming-data-from-client-with-http-post)

Comment: When I say cached, I meant to ask if they are on the network bandwidth. Isnt the bandwidth going to be congested when multiple requests keep coming in and what if I run out of bandwidth ?

Comment: I think in that case those requests will be lost.

Comment: So, the Inputstream is going to reside on the servers network then ? If yes, what would be a good approach for load testing the service and for defining SLA's ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that... I will follow the discussion for more answers.